# loading videos using fetchAPI

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, blob

i'm trying to download complete videos, making blob links for them before actually playing them or adding them to DOM, here the bit of my code that does that

```
 const init = {method: 'GET',mode: 'no-cors',cache: 'default'};
 const request = new Request(mp4Url);

fetch(request, init)
.then((response) =>  response.blob())
.then(data=>
  {
    let vid = URL.createObjectURL(data)
    let htmlString =`
    <video id="video-${id}" class="video_player" src="${vid}" autoplay muted loop>
    </video>`

    let videoElem = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
    videoRoot.appendChild(videoElem.firstChild.children[1].firstChild)
  }
  );
```

i'm getting

```
blob:http://127.0.0.1:5501/b62d9895-a432-487e-b1bc-4c670fe4b30c 
net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE
```

from chrome and this from firefox

```
HTTP “Content-Type” of “application/x-unknown-content-type” is not supported. Load of media resource blob:http://127.0.0.1:5501/b62d9895-a432-487e-b1bc-4c670fe4b30c  failed.
```

is something like this really possible?

Comment: Try a test where... You create a video tag inside the  `<body>` tag with **id** like _"myVideo"_ and with a `src=""` so it plays nothing until the blob is loaded. When the **fetch** result becomes available, you do the `let vid = URL.createObjectURL(data)` but now also add `document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", vid);` followed by `document.getElementById("myVideo").load();` and that should now display the video...

Comment: tried that, same result, i also logged `data` before creating the URL,
it gave out `Blob {size: 0, type: ''}`, 
perhaps the problem is with `response.blob()` and i need some other way to decode(?) the video.

i'm using this [video](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WeAreGoingOnBullrun.mp4) to test

Comment: OK. I see the link is on an external server. Are you not getting a CORS error? I will test this file later, but if it is a CORS error then either copy the file to same folder as your HTML/JS... or else use a PHP proxy script if you have PHP enabled in your server.